# How to Properly Change a Google Kubernetes Engine Node Pool Using Terraform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, infrastructure-as-code

I have successfully created a Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster (`$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME`) inside of a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project (`$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`):

```sh
gcloud container clusters list \
--format="value(name)" \
--project=$GCP_PROJECT_NAME

#=>

. . .
$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME
. . .
```

which uses the node pool `$GKE_NODE_POOL`:

```sh
gcloud container node-pools list \
--cluster=$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME \
--format="value(name)" \
--zone=$GKE_CLUSTER_ZONE

#=>

$GKE_NODE_POOL
```

I am checking this config. into SCM using Terraform with the following `container_node_pool.tf`:

```hcl
resource "google_container_node_pool" ". . ." {
  autoscaling {
    max_node_count = "3"
    min_node_count = "3"
  }

  . . .

  initial_node_count = "3"

  . . .

}
```

and I confirmed that the Terraform configuration above matched `$GKE_NODE_POOL` running currently inside of `$GKE_CLUSTER_NAME` and `$GCP_PROJECT_NAME`:

```sh
terraform plan

#=>

No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration.

Terraform has compared your real infrastructure against your configuration and found no differences, so no changes are needed.
```

If I want to make a change to `$GKE_NODE_POOL`:

```hcl
resource "google_container_node_pool" ". . ." {
  autoscaling {
    max_node_count = "4"
    min_node_count = "4"
  }

  . . .

  initial_node_count = "4"

  . . .

}
```

and scale the number of `node`s in `$GKE_NODE_POOL` from 3 to 4, I get the following output when trying to `plan`:

```sh
terraform plan

#=>

. . .

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.

. . .
```

How can I update `$GKE_NODE_POOL` without destroying and then recreating the resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `initial_node_count` argument for any `google_container_node_pool` **will** trigger destruction and recreation.  Just don't modify `initial_node_count` and you should be able to modify `$GKE_NODE_POOL` arguments such as `min_node_count` and `max_node_count`.

The output of the `plan` command *should* explicitly show you which argument causes destruction and recreation behavior [in red]:

```sh
terraform plan

. . .

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # google_container_node_pool.$GKE_NODE_POOL must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_container_node_pool" ". . ." {

. . .

      ~ initial_node_count  = 3 -> 4 # forces replacement

. . .

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.

. . .
```

The `initial_node_count` argument seems to be the *only* argument for `google_container_node_pool` that causes this behavior; the `initial_node_count` argument also appears to be *optional*.

You can read this warning in the official documentation [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#initial_node_count).

Comment: is this really the only way? So google cli or GUI are the only way to resize a fixed size node pool with no downtime?

Comment: Hi there!  My question and answer address an interaction between the Google Cloud REST API and Terraform **only**; more specifically, a gotcha relating to the `initial_node_count` argument preventing changes to a node pool and forcing a replacement.  If you manage a fixed-size node pool with Terraform (`google_container_node_pool`), you _should_ be able to use the `node_count`  argument (more [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_node_pool#node_count))  **without** forcing a replacement.